# Can't access the Auth::user() from a custom route file ? Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-7, laravel-authentication

For a purpose i decided to create a separate routing file for the admin and separating its logic from the web.php  but instead i am facing this issue :

```
//admin.php ( routing file )


<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth

    Route::get('/admin', function ()
            {
                dd(Auth::user());  //return null
            });
```

ps: the admin.php is registered in the RouteServiceProvider

```
public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();
        $this->mapWebRoutes();
        $this->mapAdminRoutes();
         //
    }

protected function mapAdminRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('admin')
            ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Admin')
            ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add web middleware

```
Route::middleware(['web','admin'])->...
```

Comment: One thing to note here is this that `['web', 'admin']` should be in same order. `['admin', 'web']` won't work! (Laravel 8)

Answer (score -1):

Let's try to defining the new route in config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ]
],
```

because you want to get session to check Auth.
So let try this one.